# programing the body mass Index formula

Tags: lc3

Here's the formula for BMI: `WEIGHT(IB)/HEIGHT(IN)^2 * 703`

I am currently trying to program this using the LC-3 assembly language,
I am testing out how to divide the weight by height(inches).
I am using 196 as my weight and 76 as my height.
I should receive 23.85526315789474 as my answer.
I am having a hard time dividing the weight and the squared height.
So far I can only get the answer with the quotient and remainder and I don't know if there is a way to multiple that by 703.
FYI I cannot use instructions MUL and DIV its how the software I'm using works.

```
DIVISION
    ;R0
    ;R1
    ;R2 -> DIVIDEND / HEIGHT**2
    ;R3 -> DIVISOR  / WEIGHT
    ;R4 -> QUOTIENT 
    ;R5 -> CHECKER 
    ;R6 
    ;R7
    JSR CLEAR_REG
    LD R1 DIVIDND ; HEIGHT -> 5776
    LDR R2, R1, #0
    AND R1, R1, #0
    LD R1 INPUT_W ; WEIGHT -> 196
    LDR R3, R1, #0
    NOT R3, R3
    ADD R3, R3, #1
    ADD R5, R2, #0
LOOP
    ADD R5, R5, R3
    BRn SAVE_DIVIDE
    ADD R2, R2, R3
    ADD R4, R4, #1
    BRp LOOP
SAVE_DIVIDE
    LD R1, QUOTIENT ;-> x5050
    STR R4, R1, #0
    AND R1, R1, #0
    LD R1, REMAINDER ; ->x6000
    STR R2, R1, #0
    BR TERMINATE
```

Comment: For stackoverflow, please focus on one question per post.  Ask about division or multiplication but not both in one post.

Comment: Side note: the short form for "pound" is _`lb`_ (with a lowercase `L`), not `ib`.